# JQuery .Each loop not skipping correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

not sure why this isn't working and hoping someone can help out. The goal is to retain the query parameter on certain link clicks

example link:

```
https://localhost:3000/?catsiown=3
```

```
$('a').each(function(index,item) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("slideout-trigger")){
        console.log("has slideout");
        console.log($(this));
            return true;
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("register-now-btn")) {
        console.log("has register now");
        console.log($(this));
        return true;
    }
    else{
        var querystring = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
 
        if (href !== "#") {
            href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + querystring;
            $(this).attr('href', href);
        }
    }

})
```

Example DOM:

```
<div>
<a class="slideout-trigger" href="#">Test</a>
<a class="register-now-btn" href="#">Test 2</a>
<a class="cats" href="https://www.google.com">Cat Here</a>
</div>
```

I'm having a weird issue where those first two things will evaluate to true, but they don't get skipped else statement triggers anyways for those ones also. And even then, the "(href !== "#")" isn't working either - it triggers anyways.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: When you get the `href` attribute value, you don't necessarily get exactly what's in the HTML `href` code. Use the debugger or `console.log()` to see what that `href` actually looks like.

Comment: That's what I thought but I do get exactly that lol see:

console.log("href: " + href)

// href: #
// href: #
// href: https://www.google.com

Comment: For the weird issue - I think your second `if` should be `else if`

Comment: Tried that, no luck :(

Comment: Why not exclude them? `$('a:not([href="#"]').each(function() {
  console.log(this.href);
});` Would be easier to have a class on the links you want to select.

Comment: Good call, tried it but it still seems to do it. 

https://jsfiddle.net/f4vyj0w2/

Comment: Do what? It is not selecting the first two links

Comment: Trying to omit the query parameter on it, I still see it in that jsfiddle on there "https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true#"

Comment: I'm not seeing your issue in any of your snippets.  In the code in the question, the first 2 are unchanged, adding a `console.log()` in the `else` and it only appears once and only the last link is changed: https://jsfiddle.net/6c51nLqz/  in your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f4vyj0w2/  with a console.log, there's only one console.log and only one link is changed.   How are you asserting that the first two links are being changed?

Comment: I was just mousing over the links; maybe that's a DOM related glitch / thing?

Comment: *I was just mousing over the links* - that explains it.   When your `href='#'` it's not a url like `href://#` - it becomes part of the existing url.  So if your url is `http://example.com` then `<a href='#'>` will "link" to `http://example.com#` - ie whatever the page url already is + "#"